# JSON: Retrieving JSON file from Github

Tags: php, json, ajax

After awhile of not using JSON, I'm a little rusty on the possibility of requesting the data from another domain/web-server.

I'm just trying to get the JSON resource to load onto my web server when the JSON file is hosted from GitHub. Using AnyOrigin, I used this script

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'http://anyorigin.com/get?url=,https%3A//raw.githubusercontent.com/testuser/testbin/master/data/&callback=?',
    success: function(result){
      run(result);
    }
  });

});
```

In my index.php, I have a file that references the json.. but it doesn't parse it.

```
<a href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/testuser/testbin/master/data/<?php echo $post['filename']; ?>">
```

I am a bit lost at this point. What am I doing wrong? Am I not specifying something correctly? All help is appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use JSONP as a dataType in your ajax request as you are sending a request to the external link. Also, need to need to receive the response in the callback function with JSON.

For more detail, check https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_jsonp.asp

This example might be helpful for you as well https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/